# Is it easier for a EU resident to open a company in another European country?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, spain, europe, portugal

I am wondering, is it easier for a non-EU citizen to open a company in a European country if the person holds a residency permit of another EU country?

For example, if I hold a residency permit in Portugal (where I can work and I have my own company) is it easier for me or different procedures to open a company and get residency in Spain (*trabajar por cuenta propia*) because I already have an EU residency in Portugal?  or I will be treated as any other non-EU citizen and my residency in Portugal doesn't facilitate the process for me at all?